# Angular4 striped plus sign to space in form input

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

I don't know why angular convert plus sign to spaces, not only in URL but also in inputs value.

So I could not send the plus sign to my server.

I was tested with pure ajax, it's works normally.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in [stackblitz template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dlu5a)

Comment: @MurhafSousli Angular 5 seems works fine, but i'm using Angular 4
[angular-rmzwur](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmzwur)

Comment: @MurhafSousli, I have added `content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the issue still exists. Please check link above again